# Magento 2: Show out-of-stock products in search results?

Tags: magento2, product, search, out-of-stock, qty

We have disabled out-of-stock products from showing on the frontend, but would like to override this for search results only.

How would we accomplish this?

Note: this store has thousands of products that go in and out of stock regularly. We need them to reappear in the catalog when they're back in stock, but always be visible in the search results.

Comment: I am also looking for something like this. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Enabled the products and changed their `visibility` to `Search`.
Next Set `Display Out of Stock Products` to `yes` under `Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Stock Options`.

**Update**

The product will not appear in the catalog because the visibility is set to Search. To make a product visible in the catalog visibility should be either Catalog or Catalog/Search.

To change the visibility of multiple products together, you can use the [Magento Import functionality](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-import.html).

Comment: Wouldn't this keep the products from being visible in the catalog once they're back in-stock? And we're dealing with thousands of products, for the record.

Comment: @BrockfastCowboy No, the product will not appear in the catalog because the visibility is set to Search. To make a product visible in the catalog visibility should be either Catalog or Catalog/Search.

Comment: @BrockfastCowboy To change the visibility of multiple products together, you can use the Magento import functionality.

Comment: That's not what we're trying to do. Changing the visibility won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@BrockfastCowboy, Unfortunately the only way to do this is manually. I use the mass update attributes in the product grid to change visibility in mass.  I filter the product grid by selecting Availability: "Out of Stock"

I then, check all the products in the search results and update the attributes in mass.  There I change the visibility of those products to "Search" only.

I wish there was an automatic function that would change the Visibility based on the product Availability. If anyone finds such a solution please let us know.